# ACtionscript 3 check x position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to check if the x position is smaller than a set value.

if object.x is smaller than 150 something will happen

this won't work...

```
  If (char.x <= 150) {
     trace("Worked!");
     }
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: You should show more code to know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because `if` is not written with capitalized letter.

Comment: @HenrikLensberg then you have some other problem in your code. And very probably nobody will help you with it because your question / code does not provide enough details.